# vue-date-pick cannot display the calendar design

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.7

in my laravel + vue project, i install and import the vue-date-pick. But suddenly when i run my web, this is the [output of date-picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84LAj.jpg)

This the code for install the vue-date-pick in app.js in laravel.

```
import Datepick from 'vue-date-pick';
vue.component('date-pick', Datepick);
```

This the vue-date-pick code in vue .

```
<date-pick name"date_input" placeholder="Select Date" v-model="form.date_input":isDateDisabled= "isFutureDate" :class="{'is-invalid': form.errors.has('date_input')}">
<has-error :form="form" field="date_input"></has-error>
```

Please can you find the problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing to import CSS style of that component, so add it as follows :

```
      import Datepick from 'vue-date-pick';
       import 'vue-date-pick/dist/vueDatePick.css';
       vue.component('date-pick', Datepick);
```